# Cannot access application in kubernetes with service node port

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I tried to send request 192.168.49.2:31083, but it did not work. I'm using Kubernetes with Docker.

```
kubectl expose deployment k8s-web-hello --port=3000 --type=NodePort

kubectl get service
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
k8s-web-hello   NodePort    10.109.32.222   <none>        3000:31083/TCP   9m54s
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          7d

minikube ip
192.168.49.2
```

How do I fix it?

Edited:

```
minikube service k8s-web-hello

|-----------|---------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |     NAME      | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | k8s-web-hello |    3000     | http://192.168.49.2:31083 |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|---------------------------|
  Starting tunnel for service k8s-web-hello.
|-----------|---------------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |     NAME      | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | k8s-web-hello |             | http://127.0.0.1:45767 |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|------------------------|
  Opening service default/k8s-web-hello in default browser...
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on linux, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
Opening in existing browser session.
```

I do not understand why i can not access via first URL with IP address of the Minikube virtual machine but the second URL with local IP can ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this [official Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) and as per this you need to use “type: NodePort” in yaml  that specifies a NodePort value and you need to do curl with this nodeport value only.

Below is the sample example :

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Service
> metadata:
>   name: my-service
> spec:
>   type: NodePort
>   selector:
>     app.kubernetes.io/name: MyApp
>   ports:
>       # By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to the same value as the `port` field.
>     - port: 80
>       targetPort: 80
>       # Optional field
>       # By default and for convenience, the Kubernetes control plane will allocate a port from a range (default: 30000-32767)
>       nodePort: 30007
> ```

Note that As you are using minikube IP you need to [tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#:%7E:text=minikube%20tunnel%20runs%20as%20a,on%20the%20host%20operating%20system)  into Minikube for access.

Can I know how you are sending the request either by Curl or browsing with HTTP? Can you share your yaml also so that it could be easy to answer.

Comment: i do not create file yaml. My application is simple express application return hello world when i send request

Comment: Try with second suggestion mentioned with Note and let me know.

Comment: the second work well